# How do I change a Measure data type to Dimension data type

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

How do I change a Measure data type to Dimension data type.

I have a field in the Datasource called ‘Article_Age_In_Publisher_Queue_range’ which is nothing but the number of weeks an article stayed in published status. And of course it is a ‘Measure’.

In data source i.e. within Salesforce Knowledge it is stored as ‘number’ and then imported into analytics-cloud Dataset as Number. So, this is a ‘Measure’ field in my dataset.

Now, I want to transform this field or create another field which can change the data-type to ‘Text’ so that it can becomes a ‘Dimesion’ in my Dataset.

Looked into **[this pdf](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/17/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_admin_guide_data_integration_guide.pdf)** multiple times, but can’t find it. Or am I missing some key concept or something.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps
you can achieve this in dataflow's compute function
and select text in it then convert your number t string by saql funtion

> number_to_string(number, number_format) [Refrence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_string.htm)

this will result in new coloum with numbers as text

Note:i n SAQL query of compute function don't enclose field name within quotes (')

Answer (score 0):

Up to now i know no really good way to do this.

But there is a hack:

Build a text formula field, where you convert your numeric value to a string value.

Sorry for this answer, but i havn't seen any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Recipe from the dataset formed by the dataflow and in recipe you can convert the measuere to dimension or dimension to measure

also the TEXT will work fine.